# I messed up something with the initramfs configuration and now I can't get the cryptsetup unlock prompt on boot

Tags: luks, initramfs, cryptsetup

I've been trying to setup Ubuntu server (current attempt with 18.04.3) to receive LUKS passphrase from dropbear, I was mostly successful, but then I tried a few things to get the passphrase from dropbear to unlock also the other LUKS drives that have the same passphrase, long story short, everything went to hell and now when I boot, dropbear ssh client fails with

```
 lastlog_perform_login: Couldn't stat /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
 lastlog_openseek: /var/log/lastlog is not a file or directory!
 sed: /conf/conf.d/cryptroot: No such file or directory
```

on the host, I get dropped into a busybox shell *which doesn't have cryptsetup* installed

**Things I've tried:**

I booted into the installer image in live mode, manually mounted and unlock root partition, then chrooted into it, trying to modify stuff in `/etc/initramfs-tools/` and rerunning `update-initramfs -u`, when doing this I get a line that the /etc/crypttab line that contains the UUID of the root partition is invalid, but is not clear what is the problem, as I haven't changed anything in /etc/crypttab

I've rebooted several times, but no success

I also tried uninstalling cryptsetup and initramfs-tools and reinstalling into the chroot, but doesn't fix anything

I want to setup this again, but not sure how to do this properly from the chrooted environment, what can I try now?